# Photon Energy and frequency

Tags: photons

If every photon is identical and travels with constant C, what causes various energies and as a result what causes differant wave frequencies.

Comment: If you visit this site, and follow the links regarding electromagnetic  forces, it should help you http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/hframe.html

Answer (score -1):

A photons energy is determined by its frequency. A 500 nanometer photon has a frequency of more than 600 trillion. 600 trillion times Planck's constant determines its energy. The various energies are determined by the electrons that emitted them. Electrons at different energy levels and or arrangements will emit photons at Certain allowed frequencies.

Comment: Ok, definitely some photons have more energy than others. I also get E=hf and how their energy differs due to electrons. So, I guess frequency is a fundamental property for a photon. Thus is it possible that a photon has zero hertz frequency and so zero energy, yet traveling with speed of light?

Answer (score -2):

The formula

(frequency measured by the observer) = (speed of the light relative to the observer)/(wavelength)

says that a frequency shift is due to either a shift in the speed of the light (relative to the observer) or a shift in wavelength. Einsteinians teach that, when the light source starts moving towards the observer, the wavelength of the emitted light decreases. This is wrong but sounds reasonable, insofar as the motion of the source does change the wavelength for waves other than light. However, when the observer starts moving towards the source, the frequency shift is OBVIOUSLY due to a shift in the speed of the light relative to the observer (to think that the motion of the observer changes the wavelength of the incoming light is silly).

Needless to say, if there is a shift in the speed of the light relative to the observer, Einstein's relativity has to be discarded altogether.

Comment: This answer does not belong in this site. It exposes a non physics explanation of something, it is totally outside mainstream physics, and says that people who think that special relativity works ok and is a valid theory are Einstenian (meaning what?), when in reality they are physicists and most anyone else who had an education. This is the second entry by this person with the same motif. The meaning of Einstenian is unknown, but hints and anti a number of things. And it all is his pet theory. None of those are acceptable in this site, as I understand